# Adding Removed Item to Most Often Used Programs List - Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, start-menu

How do I re-add an item to the Most Often Used Programs list in Windows XP?  That is, if I right-click an item in the list and select the `Remove from This List` options, how do I add it back?  Do I have to delete a registry entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click and select pin to start menu. Or you can right click the task bar and go to customize, then clear the list and open the programs in the order you want them listed.

Comment: While clearing the list did allow the application to be re-added to it (by running the application), it wiped out the entire exclude list as well.  I'll accept the answer for now, but it would have been preferable to re-add a single application to the list.

Comment: thats fair @jim however this is by far the simplest method, you just have to open the programs in the order you want them. Keep in mind this list is a variable setting a static value or forcing an object to be on the list is the same as pinning it to the start menu. As far as I can tell there is no simple key that controls the list, it probably pulls data from HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartPage2, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RecentDocs, or one of the program caches (just a guess).

Comment: Here is somemore info about the keys that control the start menu:http://support.microsoft.com/kb/292504 as you can see there is not one to modify the recent list just disable it or renable it. Sorry if this wasn't the answer you were looking for.